# Updating navigation view once authenticated in React Native (issue)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

currently I am having a issue with updating my state once I authenticate a user.

I am trying to make it so the user will authenticate with Spotify API, after the user has authenticated I am trying to make the navigation refresh so that the user is brought to the TabNavigator in StackNavigator. I suspect it is due to me not using the useState hook properly.

---

This page is for navigating the stack. Currently I have it working with user but haven't managed to get it working with the spotifyToken so that when the user authenticates they get brought to the tabNavigator which is where the user will end up when they are authenticated with user and with spotify token.

**StackNavigator.js**

```
// This class is the main navigator for the application.
// When the user is not authenticated, it will show the login screen, registration screen, and forgot password screen (stack).
// When the user is authenticated, it will show the tab navigator. Tab navigator will implement main navigation for the application for the app

const StackNavigator = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const { spotifyToken } = useAuth();
  // const spotifyToken = getSpotifyToken();

  // console.log("spotifyToken", spotifyToken);

  return (
    <>
      {user && !spotifyToken ? (
        <ConnectSpotifyScreen />
      ) : user && spotifyToken ? (
        <TabNavigator />
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="ForgotPassword"
            component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default StackNavigator;
```

**useAuth.js**

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, navigation }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); //user is initally null
  const [loadingInital, setLoadingInital] = useState(true); //loadingInital is initally true
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); //loading is initally false
  const [spotifyToken, setSpotifyToken] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //This hook allows us to remember the user's login status
    const unsub = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setLoadingInital(false); //after user is fetched, loadingInital is set to false
    });
    return unsub(); //unsubscribe from the auth listener
  }, []);

//user authentication, signup/login removed to make reading simpler.

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        onLoginPress,
        onRegisterPress,
        signOut,
        loading,
        resetPassword,
        spotifyToken,
      }}
    >
      {!loadingInital && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};


export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

**ConnectSpotifyScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ResponseType, useAuthRequest } from "expo-auth-session";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
import { setSpotifyToken, getSpotifyToken } from "../../hooks/spotifyAuth";
import {
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";
import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const ConnectSpotifyScreen = () => {
  //Getting hook for sign out button
  const { signOut, setSpotifyToken } = useAuth(); //I am using the setSpotifyToken wrong here 
//I think, I am trying to show the logic I am trying to do. I want update the setSpotifyToken with
//the new token so that it updates the view and the authentication is complete

  //Spotify API information
  const discovery = {
    authorizationEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
    tokenEndpoint: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
  };

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: "private",
      clientSecret: "private",
      scopes: [
        "user-read-recently-played",
        "user-top-read",
        "user-read-email",
        "user-read-private",
      ],

      usePKCE: false,
      redirectUri: "exp://192.168.178.20:19000", 
    },
    discovery
  );

  //Runs when page is opened, retrieves token from spotify and stores it

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { access_token } = response.params;
      // console.log("accessToken", access_token);
      setSpotifyToken(access_token);
   
    }
  }, [response]);

  //Page to be rendered
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.headerButton}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>Spotify Authentication</Text>
        </View>
        <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require("../../../assets/spotifyLogo.png")}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Button
            light
            disabled={!request}
            title="Connect to Spotify"
            onPress={() => {
              promptAsync();
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Button onPress={signOut} title="Sign out"></Button>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Note: After authenticating, please sign out and sign back in!
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

//Styling sheet for the page
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  headerButton: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#9D3BEA",
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    margin: 8,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#D3A8F6",
    color: "black",
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 5,
  },
  logo: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    alignSelf: "center",
    margin: 30,
  },
});

export default ConnectSpotifyScreen;
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you wrap your `NavigationContainer` by `Context.Provider` ? Something similar here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244042/20002061](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244042/20002061)

Comment: Yes its wrapped in the Appjs. The user authenticationworks, so its just the Spotify auth thats the issue. So I think it isn't the appjs thats the issue. @Peter-Tam